# How can I assign the positive value?

Tags: c++

I declared an `int` variable like this,

```
int temp1 = -3;
```

How can I assign the int value `3` to `temp2`?

I can only find the method as this,

```
If (temp1 < 0){
    temp2 = 0 - temp1;
}
```

Is there a good method to approach this?

Comment: How about using the `abs` function?  It gives the absolute value and should be defined in `math.h`.

Comment: either your question is unclear, or the solution is "temp2 = 3;"

Comment: Do you want `temp2` to be the negation or absolute value of `temp1`?

Comment: He wants to get absolute value of `temp1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [abs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abs/):

```
temp2 = abs(temp1);
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/fyXgF)

Comment: shouldnt it be temp2=abs(temp1)

Comment: oh. absolute value of parameter. I don't know how to call it in English on my original post. Thank you.

Comment: +1  This answer is correct.  But just out of curiosity, how would one go from positive to negative?  EDIT:  Nevermind, looks like Nawaz answered my question.

Comment: @jmort253: If you want to swap the sign use `temp2 = -temp1`. If you want to guarantee a negative result regardless of the original sign use `temp2 = -abs(temp1)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (temp1 < 0){
    temp2 = -temp1;
}
```

is enough.  `0-temp1` is overkill. But better use `temp2 = abs(temp1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [abs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abs/) function.

```
int temp2 = abs(temp1);
```

The [cstdlib](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abs/) provides the functions for int and long values. For float/double/long, include the [cmath](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/abs/) library.